# Comparing between-group change from linear mixed model

Tags: lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I have data for people who participated in a randomised clinical trial. Approximately half received a lifestyle intervention, the others received nothing. Measurements of the `outcome` variable (continuous scale) were taken at two time points: pre-intervention and post-intervention (the `wave` 2-level factor variable in my data). To determine whether there are any between-group differences in the outcome variable at either time point, I first fit a linear mixed model:

`lmer_fit <- lmer(outcome ~ intervention * wave + (1 | id), data = my_data)`

I then used `emmeans` and get the output below.

`emmeans(lmer_fit, specs = pairwise ~ intervention | wave)`

```
$contrasts
wave = 0:
 contrast estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1       -3.52 6.49 1266 -0.542  0.5882 

wave = 1:
 contrast estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1       -9.04 6.57 1310 -1.375  0.1695 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

My interpretation is that there are no between-group differences in the outcome variable at either time point, but this does not say anything regarding change between the time points. I then found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376251/multiple-comparisons-repeated-measures-group-by-time-interactions-with-several) Q&A on CV and wondered whether I am interpreting the output correctly when applied to my own data. Is it correct to interpret this 'pairwise comparison of pairwise comparisons' as showing no between-group difference in the **change** in outcome variable between the two time points? Or does it show something else entirely?

```
time_effect <- emmeans(lmer_fit, ~ intervention * wave)

contrast(time_effect, interaction = 'pairwise')

intervention_pairwise wave_pairwise estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1                 0 - 1             5.52 4.61 845 1.196   0.2321 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

Comment: The latter result is just a comparison of the contrasts in the former. So it compares the post-pre changes. BTW I would say that "there is no difference" is not a correct interpretation. "The difference is not statistically significant" is closer. To establish that there is no difference would require a test if equivalence against a specified threshold.

Comment: By "compares the post-pre changes" do you mean that the latter function compares the time point 0 between-group contrast with the between-group contrast at time point 1? If so, given that there is no significant difference between the between-group contrasts, is it reasonable to interpret this as suggesting that the outcome for both intervention and control groups changed to a similar degree between baseline and follow-up?

Comment: It implies that you can't prove that the changes were not of a similar degree

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your explanation.